# Apps Usage Duration and Number of times user opened a app

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I want to get the total usage time of an app in the specified time interval and how many times the user had opened that app in that time interval for all apps?
I already fetched the last time used of apps.
Please need help

[For those who are saying it is not possible here is a screenshot of an app available on store showing usage count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noWem.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this information is available?

Comment: I don't think this is (and should be) possible to get for 3rd-party apps.

Comment: Many apps are available on the store which is tracking users usage.

Comment: there are 3rd party service available in market which help in tracking search for that like google analytics

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko please see the screenshot.

Comment: @King Jass If I answer this question right now, will it be helpful for you?